# Check if string is valid filename

Tags: php, validation

I have a question. I got a PHP script (PHP 5) which is saving a URL-Parameter `$_GET['file']` to the variable `$file`. Is there now a way to check if this variable is a valid filename (for example: `hello.txt` and not `/../otherdir/secret.txt`). Because without checking the $file variable a hacker would be able to use the `/../` to get to my parent folder.

Comment: Have you tried something ? OR wrote some pseudo code? OR did some research ?

Comment: Just remove everything before `/`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You may have a look in php's [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) function, it will return with filename, see example below:

```
$file = '../../abc.txt';
echo basename($file); //output: abc.txt
```

Note:  [`basename`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.basename.php) gets you the file name from path string irrespective of file physically exists or not. [`file_exists`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php) function can be used to verify that the file physically exists.

Comment: As a side note, this isn't really checking if the file name is "valid".  It's simply stripping out anything up to and including the last PHP directory separator.   I understand the OP's intent was to do that.  But others may think this validates something - and it does not.

Comment: `$file = '../../abc\text.txt'; echo basename($file);` will echo `abc\text.txt` and it's not a valid filename.

Comment: This is not good to use, it's not checking if it's Valid...

Answer (score 7):

POSIX "Fully portable filenames" lists these: `A-Z` `a-z` `0-9` `.` `_` `-`

Use this code to validate the filename against POSIX rules using regex:

- `/` - forward slash (if you need to validate a path rather than a filename)
- `\w` - equivalent of `[0-9a-zA-Z_]`
- `-` `.`   - dash dot space

```
$filename = '../../test.jpg';
if (preg_match('/^[\/\w\-. ]+$/', $filename)) 
    echo 'VALID FILENAME'; 
else 
    echo 'INVALID FILENAME';
```

If you want to ensure it has no path (no forwardslash) then change the regex to `'/^[\w\-. ]+$/'`.

Comment: This filters out valid file names that are not part of ISO-1252 such as japanese, chinese, western European, Cyrillic, middle eastern ... characters. Also it doesn't filter out file names that have valid characters but are invalid in OS, such as COM1, LPT1, AUX ...

Answer (score 1):

Instead of checking valid characters why not looking for character you **don't want**. Also filenames are limited to 255 characters:

```
function valid_filename(string $filename)
{
  if (strlen($filename) > 255) { // no mb_* since we check bytes
    return false;
  }
  $invalidCharacters = '|\'\\?*&<";:>+[]=/';
  if (false !== strpbrk($filename, $invalidCharacters)) {
    return false;
  }
  return true;
}


valid_filename('hello');       // true
valid_filename('hello.php');   // true
valid_filename('foo:bar.php'); // false
valid_filename('foo/bar');     // false
```

Adapt `$invalidCharacters` according to your needs/OS.

Source: https://www.cyberciti.biz/faq/linuxunix-rules-for-naming-file-and-directory-names/

Comment: It's usually much easier with characters to generate a whitelist than a blacklist. For example, you're omitting a check for any "non-printable" characters (I'm not even sure how you would check that - but hackers know how to submit them).

Comment: This will not filter out files that have valid characters but Also it doesn't filter out file names that have valid characters but are invalid in OS, such as COM1, LPT1, AUX ... in windows OS

Answer (score -1):

Would that work?
http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php
E.g, in your case,

```
if(file_exists(str_replace("../", "", $file))){
  // valid
} 
else{
  // invalid
}
```

Files can be in subfolders but not in parent folders.
However, if you're just interested in the filename,

```
if(file_exists(pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_BASENAME))){
  // valid
}
else{
  // invalid
}
```

should work.

Comment: Work fine too but I think kamal pal's version is more compact and I don't want to go to subfolder.. But thank you too <3

Answer (score -3):

i will like to combine kamal pal's and Pancake_M0nster's answers to create simple:

```
if(file_exists(basename($file))){
  // valid
} 
else{
  // invalid
}
```

Comment: Combining two different solutions doesn't always provide a better or more efficient answer. Sometimes, it even breaks the functionality: in this case, the result would be "true" only if the `$file` resides in the same directory as the main script.